# Carousel bootstrap slide images using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Guys I am using bootstrap to create an image slider and here is the code :

```
<!-- my carousel START -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="container carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- inside my carousel -->
            <div class="rows">
                <!-- first HALF -->
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div id="firstHalfCarousel" class="col-md-4">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"><br><br><img id="scrollImage" style="margin-top : 0px; margin-top: 30px; margin-left : -50px;" src="images/scroll.png"/></div>
                <!-- second HALF -->
                <div id="secondHalfCarousel" class="col-md-6">
                    <p>
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    <div style="float : right;">
                        <img id="leftArrow" class="arrowIcon" src="images/left.png"/>
                        <img id="rightArrow" class="arrowIcon" src="images/right.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <!-- inside my carousel -->
          <div class="rows">
              <!-- first HALF -->
              <div class="col-md-1"></div>
              <div id="firstHalfCarousel" class="col-md-4">

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1"><br><br><img id="scrollImage" style="margin-top : 0px; margin-top: 30px; margin-left : -50px;" src="images/scroll.png"/></div>
              <!-- second HALF -->
              <div id="secondHalfCarousel" class="col-md-6">
                  <p>
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <!-- inside my carousel -->
          <div class="rows">
              <!-- first HALF -->
              <div class="col-md-1"></div>
              <div id="firstHalfCarousel" class="col-md-4">

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1"><br><br><img id="scrollImage" style="margin-top : 0px; margin-top: 30px; margin-left : -50px;" src="images/scroll.png"/></div>
              <!-- second HALF -->
              <div id="secondHalfCarousel" class="col-md-6">
                  <p>
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <!-- inside my carousel -->
          <div class="rows">
              <!-- first HALF -->
              <div class="col-md-1"></div>
              <div id="firstHalfCarousel" class="col-md-4">

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1"><br><br><img id="scrollImage" style="margin-top : 0px; margin-top: 30px; margin-left : -50px;" src="images/scroll.png"/></div>
              <!-- second HALF -->
              <div id="secondHalfCarousel" class="col-md-6">
                  <p>
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- my carousel END -->
```

Everything works perfectly but I am using my own icons and I gave them id **leftIcon** and **rightIcon**.

The question is , how I could use jQuery or bootstrap classes to swap images using my own icons not bootstrap icons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the Bootstrap CSS file and alter the code.
Or add the below to you custom css file.

Bootstraps css to change, by adding your image:

```
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right:before {
   //Reset the icon
   content: " ";
   //Give layout
   display:block;
   //Your image as background
   background:url('http://yourarrow.png') no-repeat;
   //To show full image set the dimensions
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
```

}